# How to remove a word from ID in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I remove a single word from an ID using Jquery?
For example, I have a div with ID page_getstarted and I want to get that ID in jquery and use it for something else but I don't want to use that whole ID I just want to use get_started.

Is there a way to get an id and trim it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you already know how to get the `id` attribute, I'll suggest you to create a `function` to check a specified `string` param (in your case you need to pass the `id` attribute), check if it contains the word you want to remove, if it does you'll remove and return the modified `string` which you can store in a variable to reuse. For instance like so:

```
const removeStrFromId = (strId, searchQuery) => (strId.includes(searchQuery) ? strId.replace(searchQuery, "") : "");

const newModifiedStr = removeStrFromId("page_getstarted", "page_");

console.log(newModifiedStr); // outputs the string "getstarted"
```

You can reuse this `function` to manipulated other `strings` in the future if needed...

Answer (score -1):

you can fetch id as

```
var container = $('#page_getstarted');
idText = container.attr('id'));
```

then use javascript to manipulate your string use split/replace method.

```
var idParts= idText.split("_");
var myId = idParts[1];
```

Comment: I know how to fetch Id, after fetching it I want to remove the first word from that string which I got as an ID.